# Faster replacement for Regex

Tags: c#, regex, performance

I have in class around 100 `Regex` calls, every call cover different type of data in text protocol, but i have many files and based on analytics `regex` took 88% of execution of my code.

Many this type of code:

```
{
  Match m_said = Regex.Match(line, @"(.*) said,", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
  if (m_said.Success)
  {
    string playername = ma.Groups[1].Value;
    // some action
    return true;
  }
}

{
  Match ma = Regex.Match(line, @"(.*) is connected", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
  if (ma.Success)
  {
    string playername = ma.Groups[1].Value;
    // some action
    return true;
  }
}
{
  Match ma = Regex.Match(line, @"(.*): brings in for (.*)", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
  if (ma.Success)
  {
    string playername = ma.Groups[1].Value;
    long amount = Detect_Value(ma.Groups[2].Value, line);
    // some action
    return true;
  }
}
```

Is any way to replace `Regex` with some other faster solution?

Comment: I think it depends on the kind of regex you are using... provide some samples!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

For regexps that are tested in loop, it is often faster to *precompile* them outside of the loop and just *test* them inside of the loop.

You need to declare the different regexps first with their respective patterns and only call the `Match()` with the text to test in a second step.

Comment: Doesn't the RegEx class have a cache?

Comment: @HenkHolterman: Indeed. I have just checked that in the doc. (I am more accustomed to PCRE that does not provides a cache mechanism.) The cache should work for the static `Regex.Match()` calls made by the OP. Or there are too many regexps involved and `Regex.CacheSize` is a path to explore to improve the performance (but I doubt)?

Comment: @Svisstack: You are welcome ^_^ - Just for my own archives, what did the trick ? Allocating the Regex outside of the loop and / or tweaking Regex.CacheSize ?

Comment: @HenkHolterman see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/513412/how-does-regexoptions-compiled-work/7707369#7707369

Answer (score 4):

Aside from precompiling your regex, you could gain (probably much more) performance benefits by writing a more precise regex. In this respect, `.*` is almost always a bad choice:

`(.*) is connected` means: First match the *entire string* (that's the `.*` part), then backtrack one character at a time until it's possible to match `is connected`.

Now unless the string is very short or `is connected` appears very close to the end of the string, that's a lot of backtracking which costs time.

So if you can refine what an allowed match is, you can improve performance.

For example, if only alphanumeric characters are allowed, then `(\w+) is connected` will be good. If it's any kind of non-whitespace characters, then use `(\S+) is connected`. Etc., depending on the rules for a valid match.

In your concrete example, you don't appear to be doing anything with the captured match, so you could even drop regex altogether and just look for a fixed substring. Which method will be the fastest in the end depends a lot on your actual input and requirements.

Comment: Gah! I was about to write a comment about one of the great strengths of regexps being that they could be compiled to DFAs, no backtracking required. But then I looked at the docs for the .NET implementation of regexps and [*you're right!*](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dsy130b4.aspx)

Answer (score 2):

I don't know if you can re-use the expressions, or if the method is called multiple times, but if so you should precompile your regular expressions. Try this:

```
private static readonly Regex xmlRegex = new Regex("YOUR EXPRESSION", RegexOptions.Compiled);
```

In your sample, each time the method is used it 'compiles' the expression, but this is unneccesary as the expression is a const. Now it is precompiled this compiled only once. Disadvantage is that the first time you access the expression, it is a bit slower.

Answer (score 1):

You could try compiling the Regex beforehand or consider combining all the individual Regex expressions into one (monster) Regex:

```
Match m_said = Regex.Match(line,
            @"(.*) (said|(is connected)|...|...),",
            RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
```

You can then test the second capturing group to determine which type of match occurred.

Comment: This is the only answer I see that attempts to scan the file(s) only once.

Comment: Depending on the possible texts, there might be a problem with the @"(.*) said" version alltogether: What if `User17 said "I have already said that!"` - the regex will find the wrong "said"

Comment: I can't do that, lines have various formats non for example X command Y.

Comment: @EugenRieck The OP question (and my answer) was to improve the speed of the code he provided whilst retaining identical behaviour. Trying to read his mind about what he *actually* meant to do is fraught with problems.

Comment: @Svisstack Does it matter? Simply extend the pattern to cover all the possibilities: @"(.*) (said,|(is connected)|(\: brings in for (.*)))". I suspect your code is slow because every Regex.Match has to scan the string individually. It would be worth the time to form one (or a minimal) set of regex's that cover the possibilities.

Comment: But i have other patterns too this is only 3 from 100, have patterns like X Y text Z (Z/Y) ble ble [X] [Y] etc

Comment: With that i can group only several regexes in costs of more complicated regex, this can be cause not performance gain, but slows because regex is X more compliated probably will work X more slowly

Comment: @Svisstack "probably will work X more slowly". Um, have you tried it? Regex engines are pretty smart creatures. If every one of your regex's has a fixed part (said, is connected, etc) it should run fairly fast. As I said, I suspect the long time is due to the repeated string scanning. Just a suggestion, but the other solutions still requires repeated scanning. Your call.

Answer (score 1):

I know Regex can do a lot of things but here is a benchmark with Regex vs char.Split vs string.split

http://www.dotnetperls.com/split
in the Benchmarks section

Comment: I think that site just raped my eyeballs.