# Why does this regex not work with multiple extensions?

Tags: c#, regex

The following code does not work all the time.  I have looked at countless regex examples but very few address the use of multiple extensions.

```
public bool FAQPNFileCheck(string name)
{
    if (name.Length > 0)
    {

        Match match = Regex.Match(name, 
                                  @"\\([A-Za-z0-9_-]+)\.(jpg|doc|pdf)$", 
                                  RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);

        // Here we check the Match instance.
        if (match.Success)
        {
            // Finally, we get the Group value and display it.
            string key = match.Groups[1].Value;
            return true;
            //Console.WriteLine(key);
        }

    }
    if (name == "")
    {
        return true;
    }

    return false;
}
```

Comment: By "multiple extensions" you mean something like "this_is_not_a_picture.jpg.doc"?

Comment: I just need it to allow multiple file types.

Comment: @ENC0D3D What do you mean by **multiple file type**?

Comment: Could you give us source source texts, indicating which should match and which should not?

Comment: what do you mean by this: **but very few address the use of multiple extensions.**

Comment: @ENC0D3D I've updated my answer. Could you give a try and provide me any feedback you have? Thanks.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Ok, so after all, you want to allow files with the extesions **jpg**, **doc** or **pdf**, right?

Let's try this:

```
Regex.Match(name, @"^(?i:[A-Z0-9\_\-]+)\.(?i:jpg|doc|pdf)$", RegexOptions.Compiled);
```

As **latkin** pointed out, if you're going to use this `Regex` object once, then `RegexOptions.Compiled` is not a good choice, because it will take longer to instantiate the object. However, the match will run faster, so it's a good idea to keep it if you're going to use it on several files (as I was supposing), then keep it at a `Regex` instance.

Comment: You can use Compiled option with or without ?i.  And there is no point in including both A-Z and a-z if you are doing a case-insensitive match.

Comment: @latkin I just let the default OP regex. Besides, if you are not using `(?i:)` but you want a case-insensitive search, then you have to use the option for it, so you can't choose `compiled`. Got it?

Comment: Also, using the Compiled option make the match itself faster, but the up-front cost of the compilation is large.  So if you are only doing a 1-off match, it will actually be MUCH slower to Compile.  It is only smart to do if you will use the same regex for a large number of matches. See http://stackoverflow.com/a/7707369/1366219

Comment: Compilation time x runtime. Which one do I want to be faster under any circunstance? Hm, ok, runtime. Thanks for the link, anyway.

Comment: RegexOptions are bitwise flags.  You can combine them: RegexOptions.IgnoreCase | RegexOptions.Compiled  It's not like you have to choose just 1 options.

Comment: I don't think you understand... Your regex is not compiled when your C# is compiled.  It is compiled AT RUNTIME by the Regex engine.  This is a perf hit AT RUNTIME.  It makes sense if you are using the same regex object to match against lots of strings.  It does not make sense for 1-time matches, as explained in detail by the link I provided.

Comment: @latkin Ok, now think a little bit broader: it's a regex to match a filename. Do you really think it'll only be used once? I don't think so.

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking for something like this: this_is_not_a_picture.jpg.doc, as Andre asked, you are not allowing for a literal dot (`.`) in your regex until the end.

This should do it:

`\\([A-Za-z0-9._-]+)\.(jpg|doc|pdf)$`

Comment: No Just a normal extension...but different extension types like this:   this_is_a_pic.jpg or this_is_a_doc.doc but not this is wrong._ff  (contains spaces and wrong extension...)

Comment: @ENC0D3D So you want *any* extension? What determines an extension, a dot + 3 characters?

Comment: @AndreCalil And keep in mind not all file extensions are 3 chars either.  Some are 2, or 4, or 5 or 10, or 1 or ...

Comment: @Servy Indeed, that's why I'm asking what *he* accepts as a file extension

Comment: @ENC0D3D That doesn't really answer the question.  Do you want to allow any possible file extension?  If so, it pretty much needs to be anything after the last dot.

Comment: @ENC0D3D OMG dude, seriously?! We're trying to help you because you can't even explain yourself and you post a link to Wikipedia, like if *we* didn't know what a file extension is?! Should you link Wikipedia's Regex entry for you, so?

Comment: I apologize but I want to only accept only those types of extensions/filetypes.....jpg pdf or doc only..

Comment: Oh my, now I see why your username is *encoded*. I simply can't understand what you're looking for.

Comment: @ENC0D3D No dude, you're getting flamed for not explaining yourself. Let's try again: you want to match **any** file extension or only those 3?

Comment: That's it...But the other caveat is I don't want to allow just any character for the filename as well.....(Thats why I didn't include the period in the original posting...)

Answer (score 0):

Try from `RightToLeft`

```
Regex r=new Regex(@"([A-Za-z0-9_-]+)\.(jpg|doc|pdf)$",RegexOptions.RightToLeft);
```

Comment: Just to elaborate on this solution. The engine still works from left to right, it just tries to match the `$` at the end of the string. The engine does in no way reverse. Assuming it works from Right to Left with the `$` anchor may have adverse effects.

Comment: @Anirudha Please see comments above. Thank you.

Comment: @Lindrian any proof to back your thought

Comment: @Lindrian here's a food for ur thought! If u want to match these:`jpg.jpg` OR `pdf.pdf`,the regex `^\1\.(jpg|doc|pdf)$` would only work with `RightToLeft` option..So it does in reverse way..

Comment: I want to only allow three file types: jpg pdf or doc...no spaces are allowed for filename just the characters within the  [ ]. I can't believe this is so difficult.....  None of the suggestions above have worked...    Thanks for your help.

Comment: @Anirudha: What? You are wrong and that expression is wrong. That expression matches an octal escape of chr(1) and then whatever you want it to match. You are just plain wrong on this one.

Comment: @Lindrian **octal escape of chr(1)** lol...`\1` is a reference to first captured group...Plz..haha

Comment: @Anirudha: clearly your regex skills are severely limited. I am not going to bother explaining. You are wrong, stop giving out false information.