# Using LINQ remove vowels from string

Tags: c#, lambda

I want remove vowels from string array i did it with  foreach loops but now
want to perform it with using LINQ or Lambda expression

I have tried the following code LINQ

```
string[] strArray = new string[] { "cello", "guitar", "violin"};
string[] vowels = new string[] { "a", "e", "i", "o", "u" };

var vNovowels = from vitem in strArray
                from vowel in vowels
                where vitem.Contains(vowel)
                select vitem.Replace(vowel, "");

foreach (var item in vNovowels)
{
    Console.WriteLine(item); 
}
```

But i am not getting what is expected .

Output i am getting with above query is :-

```
cllo
cell
guitr
gutar
gitar
voln
vilin
```

Desired output :

```
cll
gtr
vln
```

Comment: That's not a lambda expression, it's a LINQ query.

Comment: @OndrejJanacek It is a query. He's not trying to modify the existing collection but create a new one based on values from the source collection. If that wasn't ok then there would be no point of having a projection operation like `select`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Although [Yaakov's reg-ex solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21903029/17713) is much better in terms of elegancy and efficiency, you can use `Where` for the sake of learning:

```
string[] strArray = new string[] { "cello", "guitar", "violin" };
var vowels = new HashSet<char>("aeiou"); // or: { 'a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u' };

var vNovowels2 = from vitem in strArray
                 select new string(vitem.Where(c => !vowels.Contains(c)).ToArray());

foreach (var item in vNovowels2)
{
    Console.WriteLine(item);
}
```

Comment: I would have thought the `HashSet` would be more efficient than a regular expression. I think yours is more elegant, too!

Comment: @Sam I appreciate. To check speed I quickly (and primitively) benchmarked mine and Yaakov's by running it a million times each with a stopwatch, and it turned out the reg-ex approach takes approximately 38% of the time mine does...

Comment: FYI: I added some benchmarks to [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21903029/51)

Comment: Or: `var vowels = new HashSet<char>("aeiou");`

Answer (score 13):

You can accomplish this very efficiently using regular expressions to match all vowels and replace them with empty strings:

```
var strArray = new List<string> { "cello", "guitar", "violin" };
var pattern = @"[aeiou]";
var noVowels = strArray.Select(item => 
                  Regex.Replace(item, pattern, "", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase));
foreach (var item in noVowels) {         
    Console.WriteLine(item); 
}
```

This returns the outputs that you are looking for.

Your original attempt did not work because it evaluated each word separately for every unique vowel that it contained.

**Update**: I did some basic benchmarking of this solution versus [Mathias' `HashSet<char>` based solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21902985/51) ([benchmark code here](https://gist.github.com/yellis/9110421)), including both Compile and Noncompiled versions of the Regex version. I ran it against an array of 2582 lorem-ipsum words, iterating 10 million times against the set (so going at ~25 billion words), running it in LinqPad, taking the average of 3 runs:

```
                  Init Each Time              Init One Time
                avg ms      % diff          avg ms     % diff
Regex            586          +1%            586          -
Regex Compiled   581          -              593         +1%
HashSet         2550        +339%            641        +10%
```

It turns out that if you only initialize the `HashSet` and pattern `string` one time, then they have very similar performance. `Regex` beats out `Hashset`, but only barely (80 ms faster over 25 billion words) and Regex Compiled and Noncompiled perform almost identically. However, if you initialize the HashSet every single time you run it, then it kills performance for the HashSet approach.

The takeaway is that if you want to use the `HashSet` approach, be sure to initialize your `HashSet` only once per set of chars that you want to exclude.

Comment: **Why** trying to replace if vowel doesn't exists ?

Comment: @RoyiNamir Why explicitely check if the vowel exists if Regex.Replace does that anyway?

Comment: @RoyiNamir, he's iterating over each word rather than each letter.

Comment: @RoyiNamir I think that you might be mistaken about the way that regular expressions work. It goes once through the string marking all of the pattern matches, and then does the replacement all at once (building the next string in a StringBuilder). Compare this to `String.Replace` which is allocating new strings left and right.

Comment: @YaakovEllis NO , I'm saying : why to use regex replace over the word "bbb" if it doesnt contains any vowles ....? ( in short - you're missing a Where clause)

Comment: @RoyiNamir Again, look at the code for `Regex.Replace`. It first matches the pattern (similar to `string.Contains`), then runs the `Replace` function. The `Replace` function doesn't do anything if there are no matches.

Comment: @YaakovEllis Ok got your point. I just prefer not to use regex matching to pattern , where I can do otherwise. My idea was to filter the relevant words  , before doing the regex match

Comment: +1 for using Regex - the best solution here. Using the `RegexOptions.Compiled` (and storing the Regex reference of course) would make it even better.

Comment: @MattTester I just added RegexCompiled to the benchmarking. Surprisingly it didn't make that much of a difference (though I am sure that [in some scenarios](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7707369/51) it would be a much more significant factor)

Comment: @Yaakov Thanks for trying it. When the Regex can be reused (like in a loop or over the running time of an app) it will have more of an impact.

Answer (score 1):

Regex Replace is best way to do this.

```
string[] strArray = new string[] { "cello", "guitar", "violin" };

var rx = new Regex("^a|e|i|o|u", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);

var vNovowels = from vitem in strArray
                select rx.Replace(vitem, string.Empty);

foreach (var item in vNovowels)
{
    Console.WriteLine(item);
}
```