# Bad Regex performance while searching for times (xx:xx:xx)

Tags: c#, regex, performance, match

I have to work through a large file (several MB) and remove comments from it that are marked by a time. An example :

```
blablabla  12:10:40 I want to remove this
blablabla some more
even more bla
```

After filtering, I would like it to look like this :

```
blablabla
blablabla some more
even more bla
```

The nicest way to do it should be easing a Regex :

```
Dataout = Regex.Replace(Datain, "[012][0123456789]:[012345][0123456789]:[012345][0123456789].*", string.Empty, RegexOptions.Compiled);
```

Now this works perfectly for my purposes, but it's a bit slow.. I'm assuming this is because the first two characters [012] and [0123456789] match with a lot of the data (it's an ASCII file containing hexadecimal data, so like "0045ab0123" etc..). So Regex is having a match on the first two characters way too often.

When I change the Regex to

```
Dataout = Regex.Replace(Datain, ":[012345][0123456789]:[012345][0123456789].*", string.Empty, RegexOptions.Compiled);
```

It get's an enormous speedup, probably because there's not many ':' in the file at all. Good! But I still need to check the two characters before the first ':' being numbers and then delete the rest of the line.

So my question boils down to :

- how can I make Regex *first* search for least frequent occurences of ':' and only after having found a match, checking the two characters before that?

Or maybe there's even a better way?

Comment: Is there always spaces before a date?

Comment: Would lookbehind work here?  I'm not sure if lookbehind gets evaluated after a potential match is found, or before it checks for a  match.

Comment: No, unfortunately there's not always a space infront, so it could look like : "0A0B1216:43:11 blabla". I agree if there would be a space, searching would be easier..

Comment: You really should read this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/513412/how-does-regexoptions-compiled-work to better understand where `RegexOptions.Compiled` helps your speed, and where it hurts it, so you're properly taking advantage of it.

Comment: You can use `:(?<=[0-2][0-9]:)[0-5][0-9]:[0-5][0-9].*` to perform a global search, and after, with a reverse loop in the matchCollection, remove substrings using the match.index and the match length. AdrianHHH has written an answer with this kind of way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use both of the regular expressions in the question. First a match with the leading colon expression to quickly find or exclude possible lines. If that succeeds then use the full replace expression.

```
MatchCollection mc = Regex.Matches(Datain, ":[012345][0123456789]:[012345][0123456789].*"));

if ( mc != null && mc.Length > 0 )
{
    Dataout = Regex.Replace(Datain, "[012][0123456789]:[012345][0123456789]:[012345][0123456789].*", string.Empty, RegexOptions.Compiled);
}
else
{
    Dataout = Datain;
}
```

A variation might be

```
Regex finder = new Regex(":[012345][0123456789]:[012345][0123456789].*");
Regex changer = new regex("[012][0123456789]:[012345][0123456789]:[012345][0123456789].*");

if ( finder.Match(Datain).Success)
{
    Dataout = changer.Replace(Datain, string.Empty);
}
else
{
    Dataout = Datain;
}
```

Another variation would be to use the `finder` as above. If the string is found then just check whether the previous two characters are digits.

```
Regex finder = new Regex(":[012345][0123456789]:[012345][0123456789].*");

Match m = finder.Match(Datain);
if ( m.Success && m.Index > 1)
{
    if ( char.IsDigit(DataIn[m.index-1]) && char.IsDigit(DataIn[m.index-2])
    {
        Dataout = m.Index-2 == 0 ? string.Empty : DataIn.Substring(0, m.Index-2);
    }
    else
    {
        Dataout = Datain;
    }
}
else
{
    Dataout = Datain;
}
```

In the second and third ideas the `finder` and `changer` should be declared and given values before reading any lines. There is no need to execute the `new Regex(...)` inside the line reading loop.

Comment: About the "Another variation": I have tested the same way with PHP and the pattern `:(?<=[0-2][0-9]:)[0-5][0-9]:[0-5][0-9].*`, and obtain a result between 9X and 10X faster than a simple replace with the pattern `[0-2][0-9]:[0-5][0-9]:[0-5][0-9].*`. However, I don't know the gain in time for a C# version.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `DateTime.TryParseExact` to check whether or not a word is a time and take all words before. Here's a LINQ query to clean all lines from the path, maybe it's more efficient:

```
string format = "HH:mm:ss";
DateTime time;
var cleanedLines = File.ReadLines(path)
    .Select(l => string.Join(" ", l.Split().TakeWhile(w => w.Length != format.Length
       ||  !DateTime.TryParseExact(w, format, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.None, out time))));
```

If performance is very critical you could also create a specialized method that is optimized for this task. Here is one approach that should be much more efficient:

```
public static string SubstringBeforeTime(string input, string timeFormat = "HH:mm:ss")
{
    if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(input))
        return input;
    DateTime time;

    if (input.Length == timeFormat.Length && DateTime.TryParseExact(input, timeFormat, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.None, out time))
    {
        return ""; // full text is time
    }
    char[] wordSeparator = {' ', '\t'};
    int lastIndex = 0;
    int spaceIndex = input.IndexOfAny(wordSeparator);
    if(spaceIndex == -1)
        return input;
    char[] chars = input.ToCharArray();
    while(spaceIndex >= 0)
    {
        int nonSpaceIndex = Array.FindIndex<char>(chars, spaceIndex + 1, x => !wordSeparator.Contains(x));
        if(nonSpaceIndex == -1)
            return input;
        string nextWord = input.Substring(lastIndex, spaceIndex - lastIndex);
        if( nextWord.Length == timeFormat.Length 
         && DateTime.TryParseExact(nextWord, timeFormat, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.None, out time))
        {
            return input.Substring(0, lastIndex);
        }
        lastIndex = nonSpaceIndex;
        spaceIndex = input.IndexOfAny(wordSeparator, nonSpaceIndex + 1);
    }
    return input;
}
```

Sample data and test:

```
string[] lines = { "blablabla  12:10:40 I want to remove this", "blablabla some more", "even more bla  ", "14:22:11" };
foreach(string line in lines)
{
    string newLine = SubstringBeforeTime(line, "HH:mm:ss");
    Console.WriteLine(string.IsNullOrEmpty(newLine) ? "<empty>" : newLine);
}
```

Output:

```
blablabla  
blablabla some more
even more bla  
<empty>
```

Comment: wouldn't using an AND operation be better than OR here?  Either way I definitely want to know if it's faster

Comment: @Jonesy: it would be incorrect, this query takes all words as long as the word-length is != 8 or (if the word-length is exactly 8) as long as this word is not a time. If one of both is true the word will be taken.

Comment: Oh I see, I was thinking about it kind of reversed

Answer (score 0):

in the end I went for this :

```
        bool MeerCCOl = true;
        int startpositie = 0;
        int CCOLfound = 0; // aantal keer dat terminal output is gevonden

        while(MeerCCOl)
        {
            Regex rgx = new Regex(":[0-5][0-9]:[0-5][0-9]", RegexOptions.Multiline | RegexOptions.Compiled);
            Match GevondenColon = rgx.Match(VlogDataGefilterd,startpositie);

            MeerCCOl = GevondenColon.Success; // CCOL terminal data gevonden, er is misschien nog meer..

            if (MeerCCOl && GevondenColon.Index >= 2)
            {
                CCOLfound++;
                int GevondenUur = 10 * (VlogDataGefilterd[GevondenColon.Index - 2] - '0') +
                                        VlogDataGefilterd[GevondenColon.Index - 1] - '0';
                if (VlogDataGefilterd[GevondenColon.Index - 2] >= '0' && VlogDataGefilterd[GevondenColon.Index - 2] <= '2' &&
                    VlogDataGefilterd[GevondenColon.Index - 1] >= '0' && VlogDataGefilterd[GevondenColon.Index - 1] <= '9' &&
                    GevondenUur>=0 && GevondenUur<=23)
                {
                    Regex rgx2 = new Regex("[012][0-9]:[0-5][0-9]:[0-5][0-9].*", RegexOptions.Multiline);
                    VlogDataGefilterd = rgx2.Replace(VlogDataGefilterd, string.Empty, 1, (GevondenColon.Index - 2));
                    startpositie = GevondenColon.Index - 2; // start volgende match vanaf de plek waar we de 
                }
            }
        }
```

It first searches for a match to :xx:xx and then checks the 2 characters before that. If it is recognized as a time it removes the whole thing. Bonus is that by check the hours separately, i can make sure the hours read 00-23, instead of 00-29. Also the number of matches is counted this way.

The original simple regex took about 550ms. This code (while more messy) takes about 12ms for the same datafile. That's a whopping 40x speedup :-)

Thanks all!