# .net Regex Search and string.replace

Tags: c#, regex, replace

my xml file is around 7mb . I have to remove some invalid characters from some of nodes. there are many nodes like "title" , "country" and so on ..

I am having 31000 matches for "title" node and it is taking more than  35 mins  . which not acceptable for my project requirements , How can I optimise this

method call

```
  fileText = RemoveInvalidCharacters(fileText, "title", @"(&#[xX]?[A-Fa-f\d]+;)|[^\w\s\/\;\&\.@-]", "$1");
```

Method definition

```
private static string RemoveInvalidCharacters(string fileText, string nodeName, string regexPattern, string regexReplacement)
        {
            foreach (Match match in Regex.Matches(fileText, @"<" + nodeName + ">(.*)</" + nodeName + ">"))
            {
                var oldValue = match.Groups[0].Value;
                var newValue = "<" + nodeName + ">" + Regex.Replace(match.Groups[1].Value, regexPattern, regexReplacement) +
                               "</" + nodeName + ">";
                fileText = fileText.Replace(oldValue, newValue);
            }

            return fileText;
        }
```

Comment: You cre calling `RemoveSpecialCharacters` but the method name is `RemoveInvalidCharacters`

Comment: You can optimize this by *not using regex for XML parsing*. Use proper tools, .NET has XML parsers and even low-level XML readers/writers if full-blown parsers aren't fast enough. *(I must resist the temptation to dupehammer this to [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags))*.

Comment: I think the problem can be with `(.*)` subpattern. What if you use `Regex.Matches(fileText, @"<" + nodeName + @">([^<]*(?:<(?!</" + nodeName + @">)[^<]*)*)</" + nodeName + ">")`?

Comment: sorry @tim corrected now

Comment: stribizhev .  (.*) not a prob . it is fast . looping is taking time

Comment: Definitely do use built-in XML tools as demonstrated by Chris Davis. Additionally, it might be possible to optimize your Regex to improve matching performance, if you tell us what exactly you want to achieve.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using `Regex` to parse the Xml Document, you can use the tools in the `System.Xml.Linq` namespace to handle the parsing for you, which is inherently much faster and easier to use.

Here's an example program that takes a structure with 35,000 nodes in. I've kept your regex string to check for the bad characters, but I've specified it as a `Compiled` regex string, which should yield better performance, although admittedly, not a huge increase when I compared the two. [More info](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/513412/how-does-regexoptions-compiled-work).

This example uses `Descendants`, which gets references to all of the element you specify in the parameter within the element specified (in this case, we've started from the root element). Those results are filtered by the `ContainsBadCharacters` method.

For the sake of simplicity I haven't made the `foreach` loops DRY, but it's probably worth doing so.

On my machine, this runs in less than a second, but timings will vary based on machine performance and occurrences of bad characters.

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Reflection;
using System.Text;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
using System.Xml.Linq;

namespace ConsoleApplication2
{
    class Program
    {
        static Regex r = new Regex(@"(&#[xX]?[A-Fa-f\d]+;)|[^\w\s\/\;\&\.@-]", RegexOptions.Compiled);

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch sw = new System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch();
            var xmls = new StringBuilder("<Nodes>");
            for(int i = 0;i<35000;i++)
            {
                xmls.Append(@"<Node>
                                  <Title>Lorem~~~~</Title>
                                  <Country>Ipsum!</Country>
                               </Node>");
            }
            xmls.Append("</Nodes>");

            var doc = XDocument.Parse(xmls.ToString());

            sw.Start();
            foreach(var element in doc.Descendants("Title").Where(ContainsBadCharacters))
            {               
                element.Value = r.Replace(element.Value, "$1");
            }
            foreach (var element in doc.Descendants("Country").Where(ContainsBadCharacters))
            {
                element.Value = r.Replace(element.Value, "$1");
            }
            sw.Stop();

            var saveFile = new FileInfo(Path.Combine(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location.Substring(0, 
                Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location.LastIndexOf(@"\")), "test.txt"));
            if (!saveFile.Exists) saveFile.Create();

            doc.Save(saveFile.FullName);
            Console.WriteLine(sw.Elapsed);
            Console.Read();
        }

        static bool ContainsBadCharacters(XElement item)
        {
            return r.IsMatch(item.Value);
        }
    }
}
```